# quickfixn Execution Report tag 'avgpx'

Tags: fix-protocol

I am working on creation of **Execution report** of **OrderCancelRequest** flow in **quickfixn** when 
**OrderCancelRequest** is valid and order can be cancelled. I am stuck at the tag '**avgpx**' of **execution report** for **OrderCancelRequest**. **Avgpx** is the calculated average price of all fills on this order. So while mapping execution report tags with **OrderCancelRequest** tags , which tag should be used against the tag '**avgpx**' of **execution report** for tag from **OrderCancelequest** message?????? and how the **avgpx** is calculated????

Answer (score 1):

AvgPx is the quantity weighted average price of all of the fills up to and including the current one. I don't think that I've ever seen avgpx on an OrderCancelRequest message as that message type just requests cancellation of the related order using the orderID as a reference. Is this a case of a counterparty requiring AvgPx on the OrderCancelRequest message? I cannot really see a reason why AvgPx would be needed on that message type.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. We are creating a buy side application and for the creation of an execution report of Order Cancel Request, avgpx(6) is a mandatory field(See execution report in Fiximate).

Comment: it will be broker dependent what will be in that field on an execution report but OrderCancelRequest is a separate message type(MsgType = F) that doesn't require that field and is used by the buy side to request cancellation of a previous order. The counterparty will respond with an ExecutionReport which usually hav an AvgPx of 0 or the current cumulative AvgPx (from the last fill) if there is a previous fill. AvgPx isn't really valid for cancellation flows.